# How to insert a repo environment variable into a github actions cron string

Tags: cron, github-actions

My attempt of `workflow.yml`:

```yaml
env:
  UPDATE_FREQ: 15
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0/${{ env.UPDATE_FREQ }} * * * *"
```

Gives an error:

> invalid `cron` attribute `"0/${{ env.UPDATE_FREQ }} * * * *"`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define expressions for the cronjob, so:

```
cron: "0/${{ env.UPDATE_FREQ }} * * * *"
```

Is invalid. Alternatively, you can set multiple schedules and then compare `github.event.schedule` to your corn schedule if you want to perform a particular operation per ENV, for example (from the documentation):

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '30 5 * * 1,3'
    - cron: '30 5 * * 2,4'

jobs:
  test_schedule:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Not on Monday or Wednesday
        if: github.event.schedule != '30 5 * * 1,3'
        run: echo "This step will be skipped on Monday and Wednesday"
      - name: Every time
        run: echo "This step will always run"
```

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule
- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25928